# mac railsアプリでpostgresを使いたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql

今までpostgresを使ったことがないのですが以前誰かが使っていたmacで
railsアプリ開発をしようとしています。postgres自体はインストールされていたようなので
postresを起動しようとすると以下エラーが出ます。

```
admins-MacBook-Pro% psql -l
psql: FATAL:  role "hoge" does not exist
```

postgresユーザに変更しようとしたのですがユーザがいないみたいです。

```
su - postgres
admins-MacBook-Pro% finger postgres
finger: postgres: no such user
```

ユーザを作成しようとしてもエラーになります。

```
admins-MacBook-Pro% createuser hoge
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  role "hoge" does not exist
```

初心者の質問ですみませんが解決法を教えてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

postgresのバージョンの問題でした。

http://y-yagi.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/12/02/062354